# Best method for Building Strings in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Does Python have a function to neatly build a string that looks like this:

```
Bob 100 Employee Hourly
```

Without building a string like this:

```
EmployeeName + ' ' + EmployeeNumber + ' ' + UserType + ' ' + SalaryType
```

The function I'm looking for might be called a StringBuilder, and look something like this:

```
stringbuilder(%s,%s,%s,%s, EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber, UserType, SalaryType, \n)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Normally you would be looking for `str.join`. It takes an argument of an iterable containing what you want to chain together and applies it to a separator:

```
>>> ' '.join((EmployeeName, str(EmployeeNumber), UserType, SalaryType))
'Bob 100 Employee Hourly'
```

---

However, seeing as you know exactly what parts the string will be composed of, and not all of the parts are native strings, you are probably better of using `format`:

```
>>> '{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(EmployeeName, str(EmployeeNumber), UserType, SalaryType)
'Bob 100 Employee Hourly'
```

Comment: The only way it can fail if any of the fields, like `EmployeeNumber`, is not a string, then one needs an explicit `str(EmployeeNumber)`

Answer (score 18):

Your question is about Python 2.7, but it is worth note that from Python 3.6 onward we can use **[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)**:

```python
place = 'world'
f'hallo {place}'
```

> 'hallo world'

This `f` prefix, called a *formatted string literal* or *f-string*, is described in the documentation on [lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Answer (score 5):

You have two options here:

- Use the string `.join()` method: `" ".join(["This", "is", "a", "test"])`
- Use the percent operator to replace parts of a string: `"%s, %s!" % ("Hello", "world")`

Answer (score 3):

As `EmployeeNumber` is a int object , or may you have may int amount your variables you can use `str` function to convert them to string for refuse of `TypeError` !

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str,[EmployeeName, EmployeeNumber,UserType , SalaryType]))
'Bob 100 Employee Hourly'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has two simple ways of constructing strings:

string formatting as explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
>>> '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')
'a, b, c'
```

and  the old style % operator 
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

```
>>> print '%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' % \
...       {"language": "Python", "number": 2}
Python has 002 quote types.
```